# If NOT equal to

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a Drupal **7** website. What I want is the following:
- if a user is on a page called 'fotos(-20xx)' or 'filmpjes(-20xx)' (in which the content between brackets is optional and the x's are numerals from 0-9) nothing happens
- if a user is on page OTHER than the above, a new `rel` atriibute is added to `$attributes`

This is what I had in mind:

```
    $fotos = array('/fotos', '/fotos-2004', '/fotos-2005', '/fotos-2006', '/fotos-2007', '/fotos-2008', '/fotos-2009', '/fotos-2010', '/fotos-2011', '/filmpjes', '/filmpjes-2007', '/filmpjes-2009', '/filmpjes-2010', '/filmpjes-2011'); 
    $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  

    foreach ($fotos as $foto) {if($foto != $currentpage) {$attributes['rel'] = 'shadowbox';}}
```

This has got two problems:

1. It just does not work
2. Every year I will have to add a new year (e.g. /fotos-2013)

Does anyone have any idea how this can be written in a short-hand snippet? And, more importantly, does anyone see the error?

Comment: you can do a [regex][ http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php ] match of link, if `fotos` and/or `filmpjes` is a constant term.

Comment: Where is this code located, `index.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirement is to add a variable when uri is not present in array.

```
    $base = array('/fotos','/filmpjes');
    $baseFotos = '/fotos-';
    $baseFilm = '/filmpjes-';
    $i = '2004'; $j = date('Y');
    while ($i <= $j) {
      $fotos[] = $baseFotos.$i;
      $film [] = $baseFilm.$i;
      $i++;
    }
    $result = array_merge($base,$fotos,$film);

    // check if base uri in array.
    if (!in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $result)) {
        $attributes['rel'] = 'shadowbox';
    }
```

Comment: small bump: I noticed that this works as it should, but unfortunately it doesn't work for the base-paths '/fotos' and '/filmpjes'. So basically these need to be added to $result, but I frankly don't know why. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of the years you could create `$fotos` dinamically like this

```
<?php

$fixed = '/fotos';
$time = strtotime('now');
$year_start = '2004';
$year_end = date('Y', $time);
$fotos = array($fixed);
for( ; $year_start <= $year_end; $year_start++){
   $fotos[] = "$fixed-$year_start";
}
```

i don't understand what the other snippets of code should do, but you are overriding the same elements every time!In any case you are talking about `$attribute` but wrote `$attributes`

Comment: So this would basically create an array in the lines of 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009 ...? And the sippet should do what I said: when a user is NOT on a year page (e.g. fotos-2004, fotos-2005 ...) a rel attribute should be added to $attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just thinking about this line

```
<?php $currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Maybe this can be change to this instead

```
<?php $currentpage = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']); ?>
```

Comment: I kow Drupal has its own means to get links, but what does your example do? What does the 'q' stand for? (NOTE: it's Drupal 7 I am talkig about)